# glmer() warning message help

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

I'm running a glmm with the lme4 package in R that looks like the following:

```
glmer(y ~ factor1 + factor2 + (1 | RE), data=data, poisson)
```

And I get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In mer_finalize(ans) : gr cannot be computed at initial par (65)
```

Both `glmer(y ~ factor1 + (1 | RE), data=data, poisson)` and `glmer(y ~ factor2 + (1 | RE), data=data, poisson)` work just fine without a warning message.  Can someone explain to me what this warning means, why I'm getting it, and what, if anything, I might do about it?

Comment: rank deficient model matrix?  e.g. lack of balance, missing cell values

Comment: I think this means the gradient at the initial parameter value is non-finite or NaN. Try changing the initial values.

Comment: @Macro your comment looks like the answer to this question.  Did you find anything else Frank?  Would one of you mind putting this as an answer?

Comment: @Corone, Basically all I did was read the warning message. I usually only answer if I can offer something above and beyond the obvious. If you think resolving the unanswered question is a high priority then you have my permission to post my comment as an answer. I think what is more important is that this question is off topic. I'm voting to close.

Comment: I agree then close is sensible